How to change keyboard shortcut in activities overview in gnome 46 from super key
I cant find where to change the keyboard shortcut for the activities overview, or to at least add an alternate keybinding. Nor do I know of any gnome extension that can do this. Anyone know of a way?

doesn't the Super key perform that function? If you press it twice in quick succession, it takes you to the graphical list of installed applications.

yes, it does, @graham but I would like a different binding

I've added an answer as to how to change key binding within the system

You can change the key bindings by going to Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and navigate down the list to System then select Show the overview which by default is set to Super + S.

Feel free to set it to a different key binding as you see fit.
